# Rabbitmq listens on all interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erlang, beam

It appears that my rabbitmq listens on all interfaces despite:

In /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:

```
[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"10.0.0.1", 5672}]}]},
  {rabbitmq_mochiweb, [{listeners, [{mgmt, [{ip, "10.0.0.1"},
                                            {port, 55672}]}]}]}].
```

In /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf:

```
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit
export RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=10.0.0.1
export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=10.0.0.1
```

When i run *netstat -uptan | grep beam* i get:

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:5672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1378/beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33551           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1378/beam
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38737         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED 1378/beam
```

How do i make *beam* not listening on *0.0.0.0:33551* ?

Comment: For now i decided to use Firewall so public interface accepts only what i need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38737         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED 1378/beam` says that beam process enables [Erlang distributed protocol](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) and connected to [epmd](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) daemon on `127.0.0.1:4369`. Also beam process waits for incoming connections on `0.0.0.0:33551`. This interface secured with Erlang cookies and `rabbitmqctl` uses it to connect to RabbitMQ instance and manage it.

To make it able to accept connections only from localhost you can:

- use `-kernel inet_dist_use_interface '{127,0,0,1}'` [kernel configuration](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) flag from shell or create my_rabbitmq.conf:

  [{kernel,[{inet_dist_use_interface,{127,0,0,1}}]}].

  and use [RabbitMQ environment variable](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) to include it: `export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/path/to/my_rabbitmq.conf"` to use configuration file
- put in your `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` `export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` [Erlang environment variable](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)